# How to get value of variable call.data when use two IF statement

Tags: python-3.x, py-telegram-bot-api, telebot

i have a problem hope someone can help me.

Ex:

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func = lambda call: True)
    def xu_ly(call):
       if call.data == 'a':
         markup = sub_main_1_2()
         if call.data == 'a_1':
           markup = sub_main_1_2_1()
```

i can't get value of call.data from button have callback_data = 'a_1'

Ple help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your structure is wrong. For sub_main_1_2_1() to run, the call.data has to be 'a' and 'a_1', which is impossible.

Unindent the second if statement:

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func = lambda call: True)
    def xu_ly(call):
       if call.data == 'a':
         markup = sub_main_1_2()
       if call.data == 'a_1':
         markup = sub_main_1_2_1()
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, my structure was wrong and i found a solution. Tks